Voltage between 12V DC and AC Ground
I am sitting with a situation where we have a device that keeps failing (12v DC). I am measuring between 94v and 110v AC between the negative terminal of the DC power supply and the earth of the metal enclosure of the pedestal that the device is mounted on. Is this normal?

It is normal or abnormal depending on your power supply. Which power supply you have, does it have two mains terminals for Live and Neutral only, or is it supposed to have Earth as wel, and is it provided with Earth? The huge AC voltage may be an issue of you need to plug/unplug cables and before grounds touch you have 100VAC capacitive charge between two data pins.

From what I can recall the power supply does have an earth that was not connected by the installers.  tested this on a different power supply that only has  two mains terminals and measure only about 7V AC between the DC negative and earth.

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/524885/laptop-charger-leaks-ac-while-giving-dc-voltage-at-the-same-time-how/524888#524888 and https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/113548/60-v-ac-behind-dc-step-down/113549#113549 and https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/92525/what-can-cause-a-lab-dc-power-supply-to-become-an-ac-power-supply/92532#92532 and https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/233011/dc-adapter-ac-potential-to-earth/233012#233012 etc.. Try searching AC on dc output in the search box above.

Switchmode power supplies have a noise supression Y-capacitor accross primary and secondary of the flyback transformer.
In basic terms it is there to prevent the entire secondary side from becoming an antenna on the switching frequency.
However, this small capacitor, typically ~1 nF, is enough to pass a small amount of leakage current.
When the secondary is not bound to earth, you can measure a voltage between them, often 1/2 of mains voltage.
Depending on the impedance of your meter and other parasitic element in the circuit.
It is not harmful, I can tell because you're touching it.
So, yes. This is normal.
You can remove this by connecting earth to 12V negative. If the application allows this.

Thank you for your answer. We are worried that this is causing EMF/Induction on the device (metal back on device) and causing it to fail. We have replaced 3 device on this site and all follow the same failure (condition stays on site and does not follow the devices) . We do not have this on any other site with the same devices.

If the issue comes from the site and not the device, potential causes: someone on the site messing with it, bad/spiky AC power (does it run on a generator?), the site being highly prone to ESD (carpets...) or the device being at the junction between two different circuits between which high voltage can be present in case of fault. For example an Ethernet switch is between mains and all the ports and can be killed by a faulty device sending high voltage on one of the ports. Same for any device with several connections.

You need to give a lot more information on the device, how it's wired, how it fails, etc. Feel free to post another question as this one already has answers.

@PieterGouws It looks outdoors, I blame outdoors ;)

If the supply has an Earth input terminal but Earth wire is not provided in the installation, that has caused the output to fluctuate and may also cause other problems like damage.
The problem being same as why you get shocked if you connect your desktop PC to an ungrounded outlet in an old building. You read half mains AC on the metal chassis due to mains input filter Y caps between Live to Earth and Neutral to Earth, as the chassis is also on Earth terminal. It may damage things you plug into it if they are also mains powered.
Three prong devices require Earth for proper and safe functioning, so the installation was done incorrectly if Earth was left unconnected to a supply that requires Earth, and you can verify that from the power supply manual.

Thanks for all the answers. I requested the installer and electrical contractor to bond all the earth wires and the pedestal. They also connected the correct clover plug with a ground core and now the voltage is at 0V.

@PieterGouws The question is, the installation and safety rules are clear how to do it safely and by regulations and by common sense. Are you confident they have not done anything else wrong, unsafely or not according to regulations? You should trust the contractor enough that you don't need help of random internet hobbyists to tell the contractor what to do. Consider if you hire the contractor in the future.
